CiviCase timeline activities added by Form Builder do not record current time
I'm finding that case activities added by Form Builder always seem to have 12:00 as their time, rather than the exact time the form was submitted.
In the simplest case this will apply to a form that adds a case and assigns to an individual (as Case Client) - the Open Case activity will always have the time 12:00.
Does anyone know why this is, and can it be made so that the Open Case activity records the time of form submission?

logged as an issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5494, but this is arguably a feature rather than a bug
